# Return String list from a type instead Enum list in C# Asp Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a type Camp that returns a string list and the bellow code validates using enum, I need to make this returns a list of strings and I can't use enum in this case.

How do I do it?

```
public string getChampionships()
{
    string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp)); 
    Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Array.ForEach(enumNames, val => dic[val] = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Camp), val));
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
}
```

Comment: You can convert Enum to String, with the ToString()

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: `enumNames` is a list of strings already.

Comment: `return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp)).ToList();`

Comment: Are you trying to return a List of strings or a delimited string of names or a json model of list of strings??

Comment: My type Camp is a string and a dont have anymore a enum in my system.
I need to change these lines...i believe.

string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp)); 
......(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Camp), val));

Comment: I need to make this method return a string without using enum.

Comment: string or list of string?

Comment: *Why* can't you use enums? At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: Because my type Camp is a string tha i receive from a api.

when i run it a receive a error: 'Type provided must be an Enum.
Parameter name: enumType'

Comment: Can you expand your post and add your error please?

Comment: I receive this error: 'Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType

i dont want to use enum anymore.

Comment: Then I'm assuming that type `Camp` is not an `enum`

Comment: Thats it...
Camp is not a enum.

Comment: I need other way to make this method, i dont know where to go.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to make this method returns same values as before but insted a enum it need to be string with key and value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203535/discussion-between-trae-moore-and-jopibr).

Comment: Why do you even use `Enum` in this code, while your `Camp` is a `class` and not an `Enum`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp));` returns an array of strings, just go `ToList`.

```
public IList<string> getChampionships()
{
     return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp)).ToList(); 
}
```

if your are trying to create some type of map `IDictionary<string,int>` then your method would look something like this.

```
public IDictionary<string,int> getChampionships()
{
     return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Camp))
                .ToDictionary(item => item, item => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Camp), item)); 
}
```